# Obtaining mapped port from within docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm using Cloudfront and ECS to run tasks within AWS. I map my tasks to random host ports using the following command:

```
      PortMappings:
        - HostPort: 0
          ContainerPort: 8080
```

I need to know, within the container, the DN of the host and the random port the task was mapped to. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#standard_container_definition_params),

> After a task reaches the `RUNNING` status, manual and automatic host and container port assignments are visible in the **Network Bindings** section of a container description of a selected task in the Amazon ECS console, or the `networkBindings` section [of] [DescribeTasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) responses.

Comment: cheers wjordan! I actually solved this problem in a more general way. Follow-up question though, because your answer is a good one: how does a task identify itself within the data provided by the API so that it can obtain its own port mappings?